# Inserção de dados em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, modelagem

Bom dia! Pessoal preciso de um Help estou enfrentando o seguinte problema

- possuo duas tabelas na base de dados **(clinics)** e **(users)**
- quero inserir os dados nas duas tabelas de forma suscetiva,  assim
  que for feito o envio do formulário, os dados do formulário eu já
  estou puxando do formulário todos os dados já estão sendo pego.
- o problema e que preciso inserir os campos do mesmo formulário em
  tabelas individuais
- na tabela **(clinics)** eu só tenho um campo chamado **clinic_name** onde,
  esse deve ser o primeiro campo a ser preenchido no momento do envio
  do formulário pois nessa tabela **(clinics)** ira ser gerado um id que
  tenho que pegar para preencher a tabela **(users)** na sequência
- onde que para preencher a tabela **(users)** consequentemente eu vou ter 
  que fazer uma busca na tabela **(clinics)** e pegar o id da clinica e
  preencher o campo **user_clincis_id** na tabela (users)
- As duas tabelas são **(clinics)** e **(users)** relacionamento de chaves
  estrangeiras entre elas onde que **(clinics 1)**  **(users N)** um para
  muitos associativo
- Bom eu já fiz muita coisa eu até já pensei em fazer uma rotina
  aleatória
- mais quero uma opinião de vcs qual seria a melhor maneira segue as imagens abaixo, a rotina da imagem abaixo até presente momento só preencher a tabela users

[image: Relacionamento entre tabelas modelagem]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa tudo bem? Considerando que é um PHPOO posso dar este exemplo.
No SQL você não consegue fazer em uma query o insert em duas tabelas diferentes
Sugiro no fim do método de salvar a clinica utilizar um

```
 return $variavelConexaoBD->lastInsertId();
```

Já no sua chamada método para salvar

```
$id_clinica = $EntidadeClinica->salvar_clinica($objClinica);
```

Após salvar a clinica ela irá retornar o ID pelo método do PHP lastInsertId()

```
$EntidadeUsers->salvar_usuarios($objClinica, $id_clinica);
```

Comment: Gustavo vou tentar essa sua rotina aqui vou adequá-la a minha rotina aqui e ver se vai da certo, terminar aqui volto pra fala se funcionou, Valeu

Comment: Conseguir resolver dessa maneira criei o método pra pegar o ultimo id na classe pai e  na classe  filha chamei o método pegar id abaixo da inserção do nome da clinica chamei o método pra pegar o ultimo id inserido e depois continuei a inserção dos dados já com id da clinica funcionou beleza, utilizei o método lastInsertId() que vc mencionou valeu

Comment: Ok, valeu pelo feedback, também sou meio iniciante no php mas meu poblema foi parecido com o seu. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que você está usando o codeigniter, então para pegar o id inserido vc pode usar

```
$this->db->insert_id
```

Desta maneira você pode adicionar na tabela clinics e em seguida pegar o id inserido para adicionar na users.

[Fonte](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html)